# How can I change a p-dataTable border-bottom color?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

PrimeNG does not let me to change for a `p-dataTable` the `bottom-border-color` when you make a select.

I tried to take the element from HTML but it does not work, and the documentation on their site is poor when it comes to style.

I want to make this change in a stylesheet.

```
<p-dataTable  #paperTable [custom-filters]="customFilters" id="tableId" 
scrollHeight="80%"scrollable="true" [pageLinks]="3" [value]="dataGrid"
selectionMode="single" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,50,100]" 
[rows]="25" [responsive]="true">
   <p-column  field="id" header="Id" [sortable]="true" [editable]="true" [hidden] = "true">
   </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: ok. I put the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeNG's `DataTable` component has `tableStyleClass` attribute which can be used to add CSS class to table, for example:

```
.red-bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<p-dataTable  #paperTable [custom-filters]="customFilters" id="tableId"
scrollHeight="80%" scrollable="true" [pageLinks]="3" [value]="dataGrid"
selectionMode="single" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,50,100]" 
[rows]="25" [responsive]="true" tableStyleClass="red-bottom-border">
```

You can find list of all attributes for `DataTable` component [here](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).

Here's working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1WPQxPDgvCFSe0ayi9a?p=preview).

Comment: @AndreiChivu You must be doing something wrong then, I just tested it on my datatable and it's working.

Comment: for sure I have something that is making a rewrite of my changes.

Comment: @AndreiChivu Yeah, that must be the case. I added working Plunker to my answer.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I make changes on my entire app for p-dataTables?